# How to dynamically show/hide navigation buttons?

Tags: javascript

When an item is at the top of the list I need to remove the "up" button and when an item is at the bottom of the list I need to remove the "down" button.

I tried to do some code, but when I remove the buttons, they cease to exist permanently and I need to do this only when the item is at the top or bottom

I'm trying to solve this but I have no idea how, can anyone help me? I'm new to the JavaScript language.

```js
function attachButtons(list){
 let upButton = document.createElement('button');
 upButton.className = 'up';
 upButton.textContent = 'Up'
 list.appendChild(upButton);

 let downButton = document.createElement('button');
 downButton.className = 'down';
 downButton.textContent ='Down';
 list.appendChild(downButton);

 let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
 removeButton.className = 'remove';
 removeButton.textContent = 'Remove';
 list.appendChild(removeButton);
};

const ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
const existingLi = ul.children;

for(let i = 0; i < existingLi.length; i++){
 attachButtons(existingLi[i]);
}

const input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
const addButton = document.getElementsByClassName('add')[0];

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
 let liItem = document.createElement('li');
 let pItem = document.createElement('p');
 pItem.textContent = input.value;
 liItem.appendChild(pItem);
 attachButtons(liItem);
 ul.appendChild(liItem);
 input.value = '';
});

ul.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
 let liItem = event.target.parentNode;
 if(event.target.className == 'remove'){
  ul.removeChild(liItem);
 }
 if(event.target.className == 'up'){
  let prevLi = liItem.previousElementSibling;
  if(prevLi){
   ul.insertBefore(liItem, prevLi);
  }
 }
 if(event.target.className == 'down'){
  let nextLi = liItem.nextElementSibling;
  if(nextLi){
   ul.insertBefore(nextLi, liItem);
  } 
 }
});

const liFirstChild = ul.firstElementChild;
const firstChildButton = liFirstChild.querySelector('.up');
//liFirstChild.removeChild(firstChildButton);

const liLastChild = ul.lastElementChild;
const lastChildButton = liLastChild.querySelector('.down');
//liLastChild.removeChild(lastChildButton);
```

```css
body {
 background: #f1f1f1;
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
 width: 600px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto 5px;
 padding: 40px 20px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: white;

 text-align: center;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #000;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 0;
}

p {
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #666;
 margin: 0 0 20px;
 padding: 0;
}

input {
 min-width: 180px; 
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.add {
 height: 32px;
 background: #f1f1f1 ;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
 color: #333;
 margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: left;
 margin: 40px 0 0;

 font-size: 14px;
 color: #666;
}

li {
 height: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
 margin: 10px 0 0;
 padding: 5px 0;
}

li:after {
 content: "."; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    display: block; 
    height: 0; 
    clear: both;
}

li p {
 margin: 10px 30px 0 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: white;
 float: left;
}

.up, .down {
 background: white;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 border-radius: 2px;
 color: #999;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}

.remove {
 background: white;
 border: 1px solid red;
 border-radius: 2px;
 color: red;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Traversing</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h1>List of Cars</h1>
   <p>A list of cars I love</p>
   <div>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="add">Add Car</button>
   </div>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <p>BMW M5</p>
    </li>
    <li>
     <p>Porche 911 Turbo</p>
    </li>
    <li>
     <p>Mercedez A250 AMG</p>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with only css:

```
   /*2nd element (up) in first li is not displayed */
    ul li:first-child > :nth-child(2) {
      display:none;
    }
   /*3rd element (down) in last li is not displayed */
    ul li:last-child > :nth-child(3) {
       display:none;
    }
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNOmGz)

Comment: Great! I am so immersed in javascript that I have not thought of other ways

Tks